# Specify another domain realm for python kerberos without root

Tags: python, kerberos

As far as I know the normal way to tell Kerberos about which realm a hostname or set of hostnames should authenticate with is through the `krb5.conf` file in the `[domain_realm]` section. Let's assume I don't have root access to modify that file, and I want to authenticate on a server using the `requests_kerberos` library on a different domain than what is currently configured on my host, how can I specify my own `krb5.conf` file?

This is a Linux machine authenticating against an Active Directory environment. I've set the `KRB5_CONFIG` environment variable in my shell and ran a `kinit` successfully. A `klist` command shows the authenticated ticket on the correct service. I then attempted to set the environment variable `KRB5_CONFIG` in the python script:

```
import os
import logging

os.environ['KRB5_CONFIG'] = '/path/to/my/krb5.conf'

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('requests_kerberos').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
r = requests.get("https://myhost.mydomain.net:9090/api/call",   auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(), verify=False)
```

but that didn't work:

```
DEBUG:requests_kerberos.kerberos_:handle_401(): Handling: 401
ERROR:requests_kerberos.kerberos_:generate_request_header(): authGSSClientStep() failed:
ERROR:requests_kerberos.kerberos_:(('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Ticket expired', -1765328352))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/apps/dsm/username/.virtualenvs/toolkit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py", line 112, in generate_request_header
    _negotiate_value(response))
GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Ticket expired', -1765328352))
DEBUG:requests_kerberos.kerberos_:handle_401(): returning <Response [401]>
DEBUG:requests_kerberos.kerberos_:handle_response(): returning <Response [401]>
```

Is there a way for me to get more information about what's happening behind that `HTTPKerberosAuth()` call? Some super-debug mode? I'd like to verify that the python kerberos is in fact correctly reading my `krb5.conf` file and communicating with the correct `kdc`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a reasonably recent version of MIT Kerberos, you can set KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr, and it will print copious debugging information which will show what you're looking for. However, you have an explicit error message already: "ticket expired." Look at the ticket end times reported by klist, and check the time on the client, server and KDC (domain controller, in this case). Kerberos requires loosely synchronized clocks, usually within 5 minutes.

> I've used kinit to verify that my certificate is not expired,

Do you mean klist, not kinit? kinit acquires a new TGT; klist shows you the contents of your ccache. By the way, these Kerberos data structures are called "tickets," not "certificates;" "certificate" is usually used with asymmetric keys (e.g. X.509 certificates).

> which is leading me to thinking that the python script is looking elsewhere for the credential cache? Is there a way to find that out?

KRB5_TRACE will show that. You can also always run your program with `strace -f -efile` to see which files it accesses, as a general debugging tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not entirely sure what version of Kerberos we're using (it's a pretty old RHEL 5.9) but I'll give the KRB5_TRACE thing a try. I've used kinit to verify that my certificate is not expired, which is leading me to thinking that the python script is looking elsewhere for the credential cache? Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, yes, of course I meant klist. The klist command is showing a valid ticket. It would seem that my version of Kerberos is too old, and the KRB5_TRACE environment variable isn't working, it'll try and strace it.